# Check and remove write protection on Mifare NTAG216?

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I have a Mifare UltraLight NTAG216 (NFC Forum Type 2).

It is not password protected, but the Android app NXP TagInfo says:

> NFC data set access: Read-Only
>
> NDEF access: Read-Only
>
> E1 10 6D 0F

Looking at the memory dump from NXP TagInfo:

> [E2] .  00 00 00 BD (LOCK2-LOCK4, CHK)
>
> [E3] .  04 00 00 FF (CFG, MIRROR, AUTH0)

*HOWEVER*, the NXP TagWriter app allows me to format the tag, which successfully removed all data (I verified before and after). I can also repeat the formatting (both Erase, Quick Format, and Format all).

But any write attempts fail with a "read only" message.

How can I determine if this write protection is permanent, and if not, remove it?

According to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34390476/how-to-remove-password-protection-in-ntag216), it might have to do with the configuration pages, which can be both temporarily and permanently protected. But I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: After restarting my android device and formatting the tag once again, I could again successfully write to the tag.

Curiously, it still reports Read-Only as described below. I guess that's normal (perhaps for this particular chip) and it was just an intermittent problem.